# WPF: bind textblock to textbox

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, textblock

I've one window, with textbox control.
this window rise second window in which i have some textblock

i would like to bind this textblock to the textbox, in order to see what i've typed...

how can i do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
class Window1
{
    void OpenSecondWindow()
    {
        var window = new Window2();
        window.SetTextboxContext(textbox);
        window.Show();
    }
}

class Window2
{
    public void SetTextboxContext(object context)
    {
        textblock.DataContext = context;
    }
}
```

XAML:

Window1:

```
<Window>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox" />
</Window>
```

Window2:

```
<Window>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textblock" Text="{Binding Text}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: didnt work for me :(

the textblock is not updated with the text (i get empty textblock)